# Gracenote Entourage. Listen to Video show in background

Tags: gracenote, entourage

From the documentation I have learned that it is possible to make Entourage work in background for iOS Apps as well and developers are advised to read the  - Entourage Best Practices to Achieve All-Day Interactivity. But I cannot find this information anywhere on web site or in the documentation. Can you help me find it? This or any other documentation that can guide me to implement correctly the listening while ios app is in background.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This is more of an iOS question than a Gracenote question. Perhaps this can be useful?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW26